# How to Add a new Column to a group in Quickfix?

Tags: java, c#, quickfix, fix-protocol

Im using quickfix to connect to fix engine and receive data. But the market data that comes in are being rejected by my app, stating that the tag appears twice.

```
 20160624-12:44:36.770 : 8=FIX.4.49=21835=W34=2649=CfhDemoPrices52=20160624-12:44:37.79356=PrimoDEMOFIX55=GBPUSD262=PrimoApp13268=2269=0270=1.37203271=1500000290=164=20160628278=30/34-920771269=1270=1.37228271=1500000290=1278=30/34-92077610=038
 20160624-12:44:36.798 : 8=FIX.4.49=12635=334=2749=PrimoDEMOFIX52=20160624-12:44:36.79456=CfhDemoPrices45=2658=Tag appears more than once371=278372=W373=1310=139
```

After lot of analysis, we found that the tag 278(MDEntryID) is not included in NoMDEntries in fix44. I want to include the field in that group in my quickfix and rebuild it. Any idea how to do that? Or please let me know your suggestions to solve this problem.

Comment: I've already pointed you to [this link](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html) on another question.  The structure of the DD file is pretty simple; you should be able to figure out how to add 278 to the NoMDEntries group.  If you cannot, please say where you are stuck.

Comment: I have already did the necessary changes in the DD file.                                     <message name="MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh" msgtype="W"   msgcat="app">
    <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
    <component name="Instrument" required="Y" /> 
    <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
      <field name="MDEntryType" required="N" />
   <field name="MDEntryID" required="N" />
   <field name="MDEntrySize" required="N" />
      <field name="MDEntryPx" required="N" />
      <field name="Currency" required="N" />    Still  its not working as expected.

Comment: The reason for it not working is that the field must also be added in the class NoMDEntries which extends group. But for that i might need source code of quick fix.  Am i right?

Comment: The best option to know it is debug and see it for yourself. You questions border on we telling you everything, this is not how this site works. You have to put some effort yourself too. If you debug your code you will get it immediately.

Comment: i think you misunderstood. After the lot of debugging only i found out that the Quickfix 44 does not have field MDEntryID inside the group NoMDEntries. I precisely know where the problem is. But dont know how to solve that.  Should i have to rebuild quicfix library itself, or is there any other better way. Thats what i want to know. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've modified your DD incorrectly, because you don't know how repeating groups work.

This is the standard FIX44 DD for your message.  I've added some comments to indicate tag numbers.

```
  <message name="MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh" msgtype="W" msgcat="app">
    <field name="MDReqID" required="N" />
    <component name="Instrument" required="Y" />
    <group name="NoUnderlyings" required="N">
      <component name="UnderlyingInstrument" required="N" />
    </group>
    <group name="NoLegs" required="N">
      <component name="InstrumentLeg" required="N" />
    </group>
    <field name="FinancialStatus" required="N" />
    <field name="CorporateAction" required="N" />
    <field name="NetChgPrevDay" required="N" />
    <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">      <!-- 268 -->
      <field name="MDEntryType" required="Y" />  <!-- 269 -->
      <field name="MDEntryPx" required="N" />    <!-- 270 -->
      <field name="Currency" required="N" />
      <field name="MDEntrySize" required="N" />  <!-- 271 -->
      <field name="MDEntryDate" required="N" />

      ... and so on ...
```

Fields inside of repeating groups **must** be in the prescribed order.  When QF processes a group, if it encounters an unexpected field then it assumes the group is over.

Your DD does not match the order that your sender is sending, so your engine is malfunctioning.

Your sender is sending fields in this order:

```
268-> (group 1) 269 270 271 290 64 278
      (group 2) 269 270 271 290 278
```

(The above is directly from your rejected message.)

Your DD, however, is expecting `269 278 271 270`.  As soon as it hits 278, it ends the group and weird things start happening.

Revert your DD back to the default, then add 64/SettlDate and 278/MDEntryID to the **end** of the `NoMDEntries` component.  Given the evidence you've provided, it's clear that your counterparty has added those fields to the end of the group.

Surely these are not the only modifications that your counterparty has made to the DD.  **GET THEIR DOCUMENTATION AND READ IT.**  Then modify your DD accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will surely try this out and let you know the result. One more question and it is just for my understanding. The quick Fix has a class called NOMDEntries Group and that class has some set of variables. And while debugging i found that fix44 does not have MDEntryID in it. Will this cause any problem, or just modifying the DD alone can fix the 278 tag error.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is working now. Now i understand how the repeating tags work and the orders i have to maintain. Thankyou so much for teaching this. was really helpful.

Comment: The NoMDEntriesGroup class is generated from the DD.  You don't *have* to regenerate and rebuild QF, but you won't have pretty methods for getting 64 and 278 unless you do.  You'll have to use the generic GetStringField(278) or GetIntField or whatever (I might not have those method names correct, but I think you understand).